# Is a transition from multidomain to single domain a phasetransition?

Tags: phase-transition, ferromagnetism

Is the transition from a multodomain state to a single domain state a phase transition? E.g. in a ferromagnet as a function of field from a multidomain state at low fields to a single domain state at high fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if by multidomain you mean randomly oriented domains that lead to no net magnetic field, then that's a description of a ferromagnetic phase transition, which is a second-order or [continuous phase transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition#Modern_classifications).

Comment: No im talking about the case where the ferromagnetic transition already happend. Due to demagnetizing fields however multiple domains are formed with M aligned along the easy axes.

Comment: After demagnetization I don't think you have macroscopic domains - when it's magnetized, you have an infinite one, and at criticality there are arbitrarily larges ones, but not afterwards - so these multiple domains add to zero macroscopically, don't they?

Comment: Well below Tc you do have macroscopic domains. They can be visualized by optic techniques.

Comment: @P3trus, Not in the thermodynamical (infinite size) limit, I'd say -- those images are for finite, actually very small samples.